# What is the safest way to modify files in an installed homebrew formula?

Tags: python, git, osx-lion, homebrew

I discovered homebrew about a week ago and have been using it to install a number of libraries and modules for Python, one of which being matplotlib.

I would like to modify some files in my matplotlib installation as part of a debugging effort, but I know that brew uses some sort of git repository to manage all of its files. I want to be able to revert back to the basic matplotlib installation at any time so that if my changes mess things up I will have a working plotting library. I also don't want to screw dependencies between matplotlib and other modules and homebrew's own management system.

What is the best way to do this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not using homebrew, but when I want a „lib” file modified while keeping the original safe, I put the modified version in the local path so it is imported before (instead) default one. But if it's imported by a third module, that's not easy task